# undefined value after query a second call in mongo db in node js

Tags: node.js

I am getting an undefined value for stateName when i call a second query. I know it is the problem due to asynchronus, I have searched for it in the google for getting the concept of callbacks but couldn't. below is the code.

```
exports.getEmployee = function(req, res) {

var jsonArray = [];
var jsonString;
var success = true;    

if(success == true){
    mongooseDBObject.var_employee.find(jsonString, function(err, doc_employee){
        if(err == null) {
            if(doc_employee_travel == "") {
                res.status(404);
                res.json({result: "Employee record not found."});
            } else {
                doc_employee.forEach(function(docEmployee){
                    mongooseDBObject.var_states.find({stateID: docEmployee.statename},function(err, states){
                        states.forEach(function(statesLoop){
                            stateName = statesLoop.stateName;
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(stateName); //showing undefined.
                });
                res.status(200);
                res.json(jsonArray);
            }
        } else {
            res.json({error: err});
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `stateName`? The call to `var_states.find` is async, so the function returns immediately, and thus the variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `console.log(statename)` inside the `function(err, states)` call. Like this:

```
                function(err, states){
                    states.forEach(function(statesLoop){
                        stateName = statesLoop.stateName;
                    });
                    console.log(stateName); //Should show something useful
                });
```

Due the async nature of Node, the call to Mongo to find the state name was called, the console immediately printed the value (which was undefined), and then Mongo returned the results and presumably set the `stateName` variable.